# How to inspect python object in visual debugger?

Tags: visual-studio, python-2.7, python-c-api, cpython, python-c-extension

When debugging a python extension in visual debugger, the raw interpretation of a python object in the inspector is not user-friendly. One can hardly see the real content in the object. Is there a way to watch the python representation of the object, like the `vector<string>` in C++, which is definitely converted by the visual studio to give the real content instead of low level implementation.

ps: following is an inspection of `dict` in python.
[image]